# Can't get YouTube video time format to change

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have written a js file that pulls info using YouTube API v3. I've tried many methods to get the time to change but nothing works. Can someone explain to me how to get it to change to- month/date/year?

Thank you.

```js
var channelName = '2kolf';
var vidWidth = 166;
var vidHeight = 86;
var vidResults = 4;

$ (document).ready(function() {
 $.get(
  "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels",{
   part: 'contentDetails',
   forUsername: channelName,
   key: ''},
      function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
     console.log(item);
     pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
     getVids(pid);
    })
   }
 );

 function getVids(pid){
  $.get(
  "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",{
   part: 'snippet',
   maxResults: vidResults,
   playlistId: pid,
   key: ''},
   function(data) {
    var output;
    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
     console.log(item);
                    videoTitle = item.snippet.title.replace("Season 8 - ", "");
     videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
     videoThumbnails = item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
     videoPublished = item.snippet.publishedAt;//This is to show the date published//
     videoAuthor = item.snippet.channelTitle.replace("2kOLF", "2K Online Franchise");
     videoStats = item.snippet.statistics;
          
output = '<li class="YouTubeVideos"><a class="various fancybox.iframe" title="'+videoTitle+'" href=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoId+'\?fs=1&autoplay=1"><img height="'+vidHeight+'" width="'+vidWidth+'" src='+videoThumbnails+' ></a><br><p>'+videoTitle+'</p><br><span style="font-weight: normal;">by '+videoAuthor+'<br>'+videoPublished+'</span></li>';
     
     //Append to results listStyleType
     $('#results').append(output);
    })
   }
 );
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the dateformat of Youtube API results. You have to change the format using JS. You can use external plugins like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to format the date. Following is the pure JS way.

```
videoPublished = new Date(item.snippet.publishedAt);
formattedDate = (videoPublished .getMonth()+1) + '/' + videoPublished .getDate() + '/' + videoPublished .getFullYear();
```

Use `formattedDate` to display

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed the code and added what you mention. However, I get an error.

`ReferenceError: mydate is not defined`